# Logo gets cut off on mobile version twenty thirteen theme wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am using the twenty thirteen theme, and on my mobile, the logo gets cut off.

I have tried lots of different css coding,the last I tried was:

```
.site-header .home-link {

    color: #141412;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height:130px!important;
    padding:20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Anybody that has any ideas on how to fix the issue?
The webpage is: https://www.larvigaladan.se

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appear to be in your CSS in index.php on line 172:

Change

```
.site-header {
    background-size: 768px auto;
}
```

To

```
.site-header {
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

Edit:
I just noticed this is wordpress... so you can add that css to your custom css  if you can not find the code directly.

https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/editing-css/

Comment: @anita it works for me when I make the change to your website via developer tools. I can see the value is still set to 768px auto;? Once you make the change make sure you clear your cache or use an incognito window on your browser. I also noticed it looks better at 140% instead of 100%.

Comment: It worked! I was using it within at media, that's why it did not work for me the first time. Thank you soooo much! Thank you, thank you, thank you! Now I just have to fix the other billion problems I have with this site! One being that the other pages on the mobile version do not resize 100% in width. They only cover about 50% of the screen. Thanx again for your help!